# What is the asymptotic probability of G(n,0.5) to have exactly two isolated vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

What is the asymptotic probability of G(n,0.5) to have exactly two isolated vertices?

Really need some explanation or directions with this one!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you understand the problem?

Comment: I understand the basics, what is a random graph. I have just encountered Ernos-Renyi model, applied it to calculate the probability of graphs with certain number of vertices and edges. But that one came out of nowhere :/

Comment: I would try $n = 2, 3, 4...$ and see how it goes. The answer seems pretty obvious to me but proving it will take some exploration. I think perhaps you will need to handle odd and even cases separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand how would I do this b using bruteforce. n(n-1)/2 to get maximum number of edges, then I use combinations to calculate number of graphs for 0, 1, 2, ... , m edges. For n =3, that would be 8 different graphs, and probability of two isolated vertices for n = 3 and p = 1/2, would be 1/8. But the question above sounds so vague, I don't really understand what kind of output I am expected to give, is it formula (ie generalisation) or a number?

Comment: You're final answer is 1. a number and 2. a proof of how that number is derived.

Comment: Well, by searching the lectures, I have encountered the similar problem but with one isolated vertex. The probability tends to 0, so I would assume, that the probability of two isolated vertices is even less. My guess that I should answer 0, but I can really formulate it properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are some easy probabilities to find. (All these can be found just by looking at which edges have to be missing in all of these cases.)

- the probability of a specific vertex $u$ being isolated is $(\frac12)^{n-1}$.
- the probability of two specific vertices $u,v$ both being isolated is $(\frac12)^{2n-3}$.
- the probability of three specific vertices $u,v,w$ all being isolated is $(\frac12)^{3n-6}$.

From this we see that two vertices being isolated is much less likely that one, and three vertices being isolated is much much less likely than two.

Let's consider a simpler problem: what is the probability that **exactly one** vertex is isolated?

If we sum over all possible vertices, we get $n (\frac12)^{n-1}$. That's an overestimate: there is some overlap between these events. But whenever there is overlap, that corresponds to two or more vertices being isolated. So what's the probability that two or more vertices are isolated?

Well, once again, we can sum over all pairs of vertices, and get $\binom n2 (\frac12)^{2n-3}$. That's still an overestimate, because there's overlap between these events. So if we subtract it from our previous probability, the result $n(\frac12)^{n-1} - \binom n2 (\frac12)^{2n-3}$ is an *underestimate* of the probability that exactly one vertex is isolated.

From $n(\frac12)^{n-1} - \binom n2 (\frac12)^{2n-3} \le \Pr[\text{exactly one isolated vertex}] \le n (\frac12)^{n-1}$, we conclude that the asymptotic probability is $(1+o(1))n (\frac12)^{n-1}$: the $n (\frac12)^{n-1}$ term dominates the $\binom n2 (\frac12)^{2n-3}$ in the limit as $n \to \infty$. (You should check this.) So our answer to the simpler question is $(1+o(1))n (\frac12)^{n-1}$.

A similar argument can be used to find the asymptotic probability that exactly two vertices are isolated.

---

If we just want to show that the probability tends to $0$, that's much easier and can be done via the expected value. But I disagree with stuart stevenson's comment that this is what the problem is looking for.